# Convert two YYYY-MM-DD values to text form PHP

Tags: php

Hi I'm using a CMS and currently use this line to change the value of the date being shown.

```
$y=AHtml::interval($reservedItem);
echo date("M jS, Y", strtotime($y));
```

The problem is `interval($reservedItem);` sometimes outputs one value like 2011-01-05 or 2013-07-04 - 2013-07-05 Any idea how to both convert them? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can You change to behavior of AHtml::interval() or this is some external lib ?

Comment: Having a hard time actually finding that. It comes with the CMS component I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can explode your out put like below and disaply

```
$y=AHtml::interval($reservedItem);
$y = explode(" - ", $y);
if(count($y) == 1) {
    echo date("M jS, Y", strtotime($y));
} else {
    echo date("M jS, Y", strtotime($y[0]));
    echo date("M jS, Y", strtotime($y[1]));
    //or you can diaplay like below
    printf ("interval %s - %s", date("M jS, Y", strtotime($y[0]), date("M jS, Y", strtotime($y[1]))
}
```